# SQL IN clause RegEx

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to write regural expression to validate the SQL IN clause where values inside bracket are numbers (ids) e.g (23,109,1) but NOT (23,109,) or (23,,) or ().

My current expression is:

```
^\([0-9,]+\)$
```

but it allows also the wrong values.

I am not really good at regural expressions, also tried something like:

```
^\(([0-9]+,)+\)$
```

but I guess it's not the point.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps post a little code on where you are generating the IN clause in code.  Might be easier to address there.  Also, chances are you could right it as a SQL JOIN instead.

Comment: I'd do something like [`\([0-9]+\s*(,\s*[0-9]+\s*)*\)`](http://rubular.com/r/3YVCFbSgjH)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second try is almost there; the problem is, `^\(([0-9]+,)+\)$` would require trailing comma. Let's try `^\([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\)$`.

No idea on your regex library/dialect; maybe there's much to be improved (\d for digits; allowing spaces between elements; etc).

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's the right answer. Spaces are not the problem for me, because I am removing all whitespaces earlier.